# Migration lets me vote twice on posts

Tags: bug, voting, migration

I've noticed this before, but I didn't have enough data to tell if this is a repro, or if it was a one-off error.

Yesterday, two questions ([audio ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331960/332043) and [jQuery CDN](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331951/332043)) were migrated here to MSE from MSO. When I went to check in on both of them, my vote was gone, but the score hadn't changed. As in, my vote was preserved, but I can still vote again. It's not associated with my account I guess.

This happened once on an SO migration to MSO - score and vote count remained intact, but I could vote again on the post. Considering child metas have the same UIDs as its attached main site, this isn't a UID issue (so someone who happens to have my SO UID here on MSE doesn't get ownership of my votes on the migrated posts).

Also, if I do vote on the posts, the score does change. There's no update and re-association of votes going on behind the scenes. My second vote acts like a completely separate vote from a different user, not a caching bug.

In case it wasn't clear, steps to reproduce:

1. Vote on a post
2. Migration
3. Vote again

Note that this also applies to answers affected by the migration - not just the question

I'm assuming this is a bug, but what's going on here? Why not associate votes with the global account ID to prevent users from voting twice?